# Safey of Validating Encrypted Data in SQL Server using a SQL-CLR function

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sqlclr

I got a question about encryption in SQL: encrypting data in the application's code (C#) and storing the encrypted data in the database has much less overhead compare to using the build-in SQL encryption options.

I like that:

1. You don't have to worry about making sure you'll be able to decrypt the data if you restore the database on a different server or when using SQL replication. I know that you can generate a special key that will allow you to do that but again, too much overhead.
2. It creates a total separation between the encryption method and the encrypted data.

Validating user password is done via the application's code by comparing user input with the hashed password. I don't think anyone need to run a query to check how many users have a specific password so we are good there.

On the other hand, if the encrypted data is a credit-card #, running a query to know when a specific card was used is not an unusual task.

To solve this problem, I'm thinking to use a SQL-CLR function to validate encrypted data. It will be used only for validation and not for encryption.

I wonder how safe is this going to be, especially if I would want to create some stored procedures that will relay on this user function to be able to query for data.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "validate encrypted data"? Do you mean decrypt it on the fly?

Comment: Have you considered performance implications? E.g. do you want to create indexes in your database etc. I strongly suggest implementing one of the existing approaches (look for tutorials online) as opposed to re-inventing the wheel yourself. With security it is easy to make a trivial mistake that will render all of your efforts mute. It is all about the weakest link in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

You are just asking for PCI problems I think. Why do you need to know when a specific card was used? For purposes of analytics/reporting or investigations/disputes/etc.

Your merchant processor (I am assuming you are a merchant based on the post) likely has ways to tokenize the actual card number at the point of sale. That token will still allow you to do analytics/reporting.

Storing encrypted data in the database, which was encrypted in the application layer, and then providing a way to decrypt in the database would likely ruin all the benefits of encryption.

Could you encrypt the card number in your C# app and then query that database using the already encrypted value?

Can you help with “validate encrypted data”?